# How to print a word (URL name) that appears multiple times in a TCL variable?

Tags: regex, excel, tcl

Following is my TCL script:

```
set line { 
Jul 24 21:06:40 2014: %AUTH-6-INFO: login[1765]: user 'admin' on 'pts/1' logged
Jul 24 21:05:15 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL www.58.net. Flow: 0x2
Jul 24 21:04:39 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL static.58.com. Flow:
Jul 24 21:04:38 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL www.google-analytics.
com. Flow: 0x2265394048.
Jul 24 21:04:36 2014: %DATAPLANE-5-: Unrecognized HTTP URL track.58.co.in. Flow: 0
}




if {[regexp -all {Unrecognized HTTP URL ([a-z0-9.]*) Flow} $line junk one]} {
puts $one
}
```

Using the above TCL script, I want to grep the URL names in the "$line" variable. Now am able to grep only URL name that appears at the end (track.58.co.in.). How to grep all URL names using TCL regular expression.

And also I want to export these grepped URL names to a Microsoft Excel file.How to do this? Please help me with your ideas.

Thanks,

Balu P.

Comment: Can you explain in what way you want the export to Excel to happen? Direct data transfer is possible but quite hard. Transferring by file is a lot easier. Should the URLs be on rows or in columns?

Comment: When I browse a URL, I am collecting the data (URL names that appears in my device log). Like this i need to do for 1000+ websites. I have automated this. My requirement is : STEP 1: Browse a URL. STEP 2: Export the URL names appears in device log to excel sheet (in row format). STEP 3: close the browser. I need to to these 3 steps for all websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(My old answer was kind of rambling and a bit change-for-change's-sake, this one is somewhat better. Note that my answer is now very similar to glenn jackman's answer. There are a couple of subtle differences left, though. Since the answer was accepted, I've kept it at the end of the text.)

Instead of

```
if {[regexp -all {Unrecognized HTTP URL ([a-z0-9.]*) Flow} $line junk one]} {
    puts $one
}
```

use

```
set urls {}
foreach {junk url} [regexp -all -inline {Unrecognized HTTP URL ([a-z0-9.]*) Flow} $line] {
    lappend urls [string trim $url .]
}
```

or (Tcl 8.6+)

```
set urls [lmap {junk url} [regexp -all -inline {Unrecognized HTTP URL ([a-z0-9.]*) Flow} $line] {string trim $url .}]
```

Invoking `regexp` with `-all` and variable names stores the last set of matches in those variables and returns true or false indicating whether there was a match or not. Invoking with `-inline` instead returns a list that is the concatenation of all sets of matches (if this list is empty, there was no match). By traversing the returned list in this case with `foreach` or `lmap` and picking out the item you want you can collect a list of urls.

The log adds a dot after each url that you probably don't want, and the `string trim $url .` fixes that (it will also remove leading dots, should they appear). Using the regular expressions `{Unrecognized HTTP URL ([a-z0-9.]*)\. Flow}` or `{Unrecognized HTTP URL (.*?)\. Flow}` is another way to fix that, by excluding that dot from the capture.

Note that the regular expression you use does not match all valid urls, and it does match a few invalid ones (which isn't a great problem here since you're extracting actual logged urls). Specifically, it misses the third url because of the line break before "com". If this is a problem, it might make sense to deliberately overmatch the urls:

```
regexp -all -inline {Unrecognized HTTP URL (.*?) Flow} $line
```

which uses a non-greedy match to pick up *anything* (including embedded whitespace) between "URL" and "Flow". In the next step, you can pass the url list through a filter that discards or flags any urls that don't seem valid to you.

The simplest way of exporting the URLs to Excel should be to write them to a text file:

```
package require fileutil
::fileutil::writeFile urllist.txt [join $urls \n]\n
```

or (again assuming Tcl 8.6)

```
try {
    open urllist.txt w
} on ok f {
    chan puts $f [join $urls \n]
} finally {
    catch {chan close $f}
}
```

Then open the file in Excel; each URL will be in the first column of its own row.

Documentation: [catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm), [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [if](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/if.htm), [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm), [try](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/try.htm)

#### Old answer

You can get all the URLs with this command:

```
lmap item [regexp -all -inline {URL\s+\S+} $line] {
    string trimright [lindex $item 1] .
}
```

If you use `-all` and match variables (in your case, `junk` and `one`), you only get the last match. Instead, use `-all` and `-inline` together, which gives you a list of matches. You really only need to match the sequence `"URL"`, one or more space characters (`\s+`), and then a sequence of non-space characters (`\S+`). This gives you the list

```
{{URL www.58.net} {URL static.58.com} {URL www.google-analytics} {URL track.58.co.in}}
```

If no part of `$line` matches the regular expression, the list will be empty.

If you want to print all the URLs, you can write:

```
set urls [lmap item [regexp -all -inline {URL\s+\S+} $line] {
    string trimright [lindex $item 1] .
}]
foreach url $urls {
    puts $url
}
```

If you have Tcl 8.6 you can use the `lmap` command to map that list to another list consisting of the second element of every element in the first list.

If you have an older version of Tcl, the following should do:

```
set urls [list]
foreach item [regexp -all -inline {URL\s+\S+} $line] {
    lappend urls [string trimright [lindex $item 1] .]
}
foreach url $urls {
    puts $url
}
```

Now, you could have used a capture around the `\S+` in the regular expression to get a list where every other element (element #1, #3, and so on) is the URL, but that actually makes it a little bit harder to get the list of URLs (glenn jackman has taken that route in his answer).

Note that the third URL is corrupted because there is white space inside it. Did this happen when you pasted the example, or can such stray space characters occur in real data?

(Description of how to export to Excel moved to new answer.)

Documentation: [catch](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/catch.htm), [chan](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/chan.htm), [foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm), [lappend](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lappend.htm), [lindex](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lindex.htm), [lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm), [open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm), [try](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/try.htm)

(Note: the 'Hoodiecrow' mentioned in the comments is me, I used that nick earlier.)

Comment: Hi Hoodiecrow. Thanks for your help. I am using TCL 8.5. Following code works fine. set res [list]
foreach item [regexp -all -inline {URL\s+\S+} $line] {
    lappend res [lindex $item 1]
}
puts $res   .. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thanks a lot Hoodiecrow... Now I am able to export all urls to excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

```
% regexp -inline -all {HTTP URL (\S+)\.} $line
{HTTP URL www.58.net.} www.58.net {HTTP URL static.58.com.} static.58.com {HTTP URL www.google-analytics.} www.google-analytics {HTTP URL track.58.co.in.} track.58.co.in
% foreach {match submatch} [regexp -inline -all {HTTP URL (\S+)\.} $line] {
    lappend urls $submatch
}
% set urls
www.58.net static.58.com www.google-analytics track.58.co.in
```